# I'm checking the values of the same type T but still getting the error of type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, recursive-datastructures

I made a function to check if the binary tree is a Binary Search Tree, I'm doing it by the famous way of creating the upper and lower bounds for each node value. But when I'm checking that if my node value is lesser than the minimum bound value and the maximum bound value is lesser than the given node value, it should return false. but there is a compiler error of type mismatch...

```
val isBinarySearchTree: Boolean
    get() = isBST(this,min = null,max = null)

    private fun isBST(tree: BinaryTreeNode<T>?, min: T?, max: T?): Boolean {

                tree ?: return true

        if (min != null && tree.value <= min) { //the error in <=
            return false
        } else if (max != null && tree.value > max) { //error in >
            return false
        }

        return isBST(tree.leftChildNode, min, tree.value) &&
                isBST(tree.rightChildNode, tree.value, max)
    }
```

And the error says...

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates 
is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public fun 
String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Int defined 
in kotlin.text
```

How there's a type mismatch when I'm checking both values of type T min/max are both of type T and BinaryTreeNode is also. Please Explain.

Comment: I've got confused that how the values of min and max would be updated so, I want to debug it to know how the values are changing on each recursive call. So, if the error is not resolved how come I would debug it?.

Comment: Not all types are comparable, most of them aren't. If you didn't bound `T` to a specific type, then it could be almost anything, including one of not-comparable types.

Comment: Try to declare your `T` as `T : Comparable<T>`.

Comment: My problem solved. Thanks.